# Find difference between 2 most recent weeks Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested, offset

I have the below table, and have created the **Wk2-Wk3** column by using a nested IF/AND function

```
    =
IF(AND(C3="Newbie",D3="Promise"),"N-P",
IF(AND(C3="Newbie",D3="Sleepy"),"N-S",
...
IF(AND(C3="Broken Promise",D3="Newbie"),"Bp-N",
IF(AND(C3="Fallen Star",D3="Newbie"),"Fs-N"
)))))))))))))
```

| ID | Wk 1 | Wk 2 | Wk 3 | Wk2-Wk3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Newbie | Promise | Waning Promise | P-Wp |
| 2 | Newbie | Sleepy | Hibernating | S-H |
| 3 | Promise | Promise | Star | P-S |
| 4 | Promise | Waning Promise | Broken Promise | Wp-Bp |
| 5 | Hibernating | Hibernating | Newbie | H-N |
| 6 | Newbie | Newbie | Promise | N-P |

However, as the weeks progress I will be adding additional 'Wk' columns and therefore the last column will be changing to **Wk3-Wk4**, **Wk4-Wk5,**
.. and so on.

I don't want to have to keep altering cell references. Is there a way to find the last column using a fixed formula that always uses the two latest weeks.

I tried using OFFSET, but cannot find a way to reference in relation to the formula cell.
The following would not work:

```
 =
IF(AND(((OFFSET(E2,0,-2))="Newbie",((OFFSET(E2,0,-1))="Promise"),"N-P",
IF(AND(((OFFSET(E2,0,-2))="Newbie",((OFFSET(E2,0,-1))="Sleepy"),"N-S",
...
IF(AND(((OFFSET(E2,0,-2))="Broken Promise",((OFFSET(E2,0,-1))="Newbie"),"Bp-N",
IF(AND(((OFFSET(E2,0,-2))="Fallen Star",((OFFSET(E2,0,-1))="Newbie"),"Fs-N"
)))))))))))))
```

Using latest version of Excel, thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively use `INDEX()` to retrieve the two cells to the left of the cell holding the formula:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=REDUCE("",INDEX(2:2,COLUMN()-{2,1}),LAMBDA(a,b,TEXTJOIN("-",,a,PROPER(CONCAT(LEFT(TEXTSPLIT(b," ")))))))
```

Looking at the logic in your `IF()` it seems you don't really need all these nested statements if you actually just need the first letter of each word. I did mimic this logic and used `TEXTSPLIT()` to retrieve every leftmost character of each word in the cells, concatenate them and use `PROPER()` before `TEXTJOIN()`.

This would, however, require access to ms365's insiders channel.

Comment: Thankyou! I hadn't thought of that. although can you explain the use of Lambda in this formula?

Comment: @CodeBob, we need to use `REDUCE()` therefor `LAMBDA()` to iterate both cells since `TEXTSPLIT()` is in the equation. Glad it helped.

Comment: Do you know how I would adjust this formula to show me the previous difference e.g. Wk1-Wk2 for row 2 would be N-P

Comment: Do you mean change `{2,1}` to `{3,2}` @CodeBob?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, then [`OFFSET`](https://support.microsoft.com/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) is indeed what you can use, it just might seem momentarily confusing until you see it in action.

**Try this demo on a new worksheet:**

- In the first 3 cells (`A1:C1`) enter "whatever" random values.  I used 1,2,3, like this:
  [image: ss]
- In `D1` enter formula: `=OFFSET(D1,0,-2)`
- In `E1` enter formula: `=OFFSET(E1,0,-2)`

Note that both formulas refer to *themselves*.  With most functions, this would create a [circular reference](https://support.microsoft.com/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123) error, but in this case, it's not looking for a value in that cell, just a starting point.

After the cell reference, the next two values in the function are the **number of rows**, and then **number of columns**, to offset by.  **Negative** numbers would count "**up**" for rows, or "**left**" for columns, and **positive** numbers count "**down**" and "**right**".

Technically, [`OFFSET`](https://support.microsoft.com/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) can take 2 other values too (for 5 parameters in total) but in this case, you can ignore the last 2. (They are to specify height and width, irrelevant unless you get into working with [array formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).)

So, the function in `D1` is offsetting from cell `D1` (itself), by **zero** rows (so *neither up nor down*), and "***2** columns to the **left***".

→ And now, if you drag `D1` and `E1` elsewhere (or insert columns/rows, etc) those 2 cells will automatically count the offset from the new location.

Just make sure you keep them as [relative](https://support.microsoft.com/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) references (so `D1`, **not** `$D$1`) or else it will count from `D1` regardless of where you move the formula.

*...clear as mud?* :-)

---

As an afterthought, here are a couple of other ways to visualize how `OFFSET` counts the cells to offset:
[image: ss2] [image: ss3]

Comment: I tried that method but no luck (please see question, I've amended it to include that), any ideas?

Comment: Did you try setting up the example like I explained, an moving around the cells? There should be no reason it wouldn't work. Did you get an error, or what didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookup table (**Insert > Table** from the ribbon, or alternatively create an ordinary range and use cell references instead of the table syntax in the formula below).

| Value | Abbreviation |
| --- | --- |
| Newbie | N |
| Promise | P |
| Waning promise | Wp |
| ... | ... |

From this, the value in your `Wk2-Wk3` column can be calculated with a `VLOOKUP()`, `XLOOKUP()` or `INDEX(MATCH())`. For example,

```
=VLOOKUP(C3,LookupTable[[Value]:[Abbreviation]],2,FALSE)&"-"&VLOOKUP(D3,LookupTable[[Value]:[Abbreviation]],2,FALSE)
```

where `LookupTable` is the name of the table (you can set this on the "Table Design" ribbon tab).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did it like this, using text functions:

[image]

```
IF(IFERROR(FIND(" ",C3,1),0),LEFT(C3,1)&LOWER(MID(C3,FIND(" ",C3,1)+1,1)),LEFT(C3,1))&"-"&IF(IFERROR(FIND(" ",D3,1),0),LEFT(D3,1)&LOWER(MID(D3,FIND(" ",D3,1)+1,1)),LEFT(D3,1))
```

And, if you add the new week data columns appropriately then all you need to do is drag right...

[image]